# Setar valores ou não em variáveis c++

Tags: c++, variáveis

Boa noite.
Devo ou não setar valores nas variáveis ao cria-las em c++?
Um exemplo:

```
int x = 0;
int y;
```

Qual a diferença nesses dois casos?
E o que acontece na memória quando eu inicializo ela com 0 e sem ele.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No caso apresentado, ambas as variáveis seriam inicializadas com o valor 0 (no primeiro caso de forma explícita e, no segundo, porque é o valor omisso para variáveis do tipo em causa).

No entanto é importante frisar o seguinte, de uma forma sucinta: atribuir valores às variáveis aquando a sua declaração é uma boa prática, dado que o processo de declaração da mesma implica que irá apontar para uma determinada localização da memória. Quando se acede à variável, o programa irá devolver o valor armazenado nessa localização (em muitos casos é simplesmente lixo). Se a variável não for inicializada, é possível que apareça qualquer valor indeterminado *a priori* e não o seu pretenso valor omisso.

Preste atenção a este exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct teste{
    int variavel;
};

int main(){

    teste a;
    cout << a.variavel;
    return 0;

}
```

No meu caso, o resultado devolvido foi `36` dado que era o valor que sucedia estar armazenado na localização da memória em particular e não o valor por omissão de `0`. No seu caso será seguramente outro qualquer.

Em suma, algumas vantagens serão:

- permite uma maior legibilidade do código, bem como uma melhor manutenção do mesmo
- evita que possam surgir eventuais erros de execução por estas não estarem devidamente inicializadas, bem como alguns erros pelo facto de ser atribuído um valor indeterminado

Comment: Só uma consideração: o valor na variável não necessariamente será exatamente o que estava na posição da memória. O valor é simplesmente indeterminado. O compilador está livre para colocar o que quiser lá. O compilador pode até mesmo colocar valores específicos lá quando compilando no modo de depuração, por exemplo, para ajudar a encontrar bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Variáveis globais ou estáticas não inicializadas pelo programador são inicializadas pelo compilador com o construtor default. Na prática, variáveis dos tipos "nativos" (int, char, bool, etc) são inicializadas com 0, convertido para o tipo da variável (p. ex.: para tipo bool, 0 é convertido para false).

PS. os tipos "nativos" são normalmente classificados como "POD" (Plain Old Datatype).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int x = 0;
int y;

int main()
{
   cout << "x=" << x << endl; // zero
   cout << "y=" << y << endl; // zero
}
```

Variáveis locais não estáticas não inicializadas pelo programador são inicializadas pelo compilador com o construtor default, **com exceção de variáveis POD** (ver acima o que é POD).

Na prática isso significa que para variáveis locais não estáticas POD não inicializadas o valor inicial é imprevisível ("lixo").

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int x = 0;
   int y;
   cout << "x=" << x << endl; // zero
   cout << "y=" << y << endl; // ???
}
```