# O valor de uma variável int não atribuída em C++ não é 0 (zero)?

Tags: c++, característica-linguagem

Estou tendo o meu primeiro contato sério com C++.

Eu queria ver o que acontecia se eu somasse um valor `int` de uma variável atribuída com outro sem atribuir, e veja o que aconteceu:

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int num;
    int num2; // Não atribuido

    num = 10;

    printf("O valor é %d\n", num + num2);

    return 0;
}
```

O resultado obtido foi:

> O valor é 134513787

Eu não estou fazendo nenhuma crítica à linguagem, mas eu queria entender qual foi o motivo de o valor impresso tersido esse, ao invés de imprimir "O valor é 10", já que `num2`  não tem nenhum inteiro atribuído.

Existe alguma explicação para que o valor retornado seja esse?

Comment: @Bacco A resposta da pergunta linkada diz que o valor deveria ser zero em exemplos como o desta pergunta. O exemplo que ele dá de lixo de memória é com struct.

Comment: Coloquei uma segunda resposta para a pergunta [indicada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103291/setar-valores-ou-n%C3%A3o-em-vari%C3%A1veis-c), espero que seja mais clara...

Comment: Obrigado @JoséX, agora sim entendi como funciona.